# AngularJS - how to find the name of the model property at runtime

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how at runtime I can know the name of the viewmodel property a DOM element is bound to.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.MyProperty" myDirectiveThatDoesSomething />
```

inside the code for myDirectiveThatDoesSomething, I want to know that the input element is bound to vm.MyProperty

Thanks in advance for your guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not use the `iAttrs` argument passed to the directive's `link` method?

```
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
  $log.debug(iAttrs.ngModel)
}
```

Comment: couldn't you also (in theory at least) use the fourth argument for the link function, the ngModel controller? **Update** yeah, controller attribute works too.

Comment: @Jhecht that would get you the model but I'm not sure if it would get you the actual text of the attribute. I could be wrong but I couldn't see any way to do so

Comment: true. I guess it'll just depend on what exactly he's looking for.